Is programatic creation of tenants with standard providers not possible with firebase auth/identity platform?
The documentation mentions:

Note: The default supported identity providers (such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, and Microsoft) cannot be configured using the Admin SDK; configure them manually using the Google Cloud console. Be aware that when configuring these providers, their tenants will inherit the whitelisted domains and authenticated redirect URIs of their parent project.

We are trying to use multi-tenancy with a single firebase app and we need those users to be able to log into the tenant via google or Microsoft. Having to manually add those providers for each tenant is not feasible as this would need to occur rapidly when the user is creating their organization. The user creates their organization and then immediately needs to be able to log in with Google or Microsoft via firebase auth using their tenant. I need to be able to create the tenant and enable the provides programmatically.
Please suggest workarounds or clarify how we can pragmatically create a tenant with standard providers without manually creating each one or each tenant in the console.
